# How do I suppress the output in subprocess.call, but save the output?

Tags: python, process, mediainfo

At the moment the code I have is

```
print ("Getting MediaInfo...")
mediainfo_command = ("mediainfo", input_file_full)
mediainfo = (subprocess.call(mediainfo_command))
```

So what I want to do is save the output of the subprocess.call into the variable mediainfo. But I don't want to display the actual output of the command in the terminal.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also want to look at [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

```
print ("Getting MediaInfo...")
mediainfo_command = ["mediainfo", input_file_full]
mediainfo = subprocess.check_output(mediainfo_command)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use subprocess.Popen.communicate instead.

```
print ("Getting MediaInfo...")
mediainfo_command = ["mediainfo", input_file_full]
proc = subprocess.Popen(mediainfo_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
mediainfo, mediaerr = proc.communicate()
```